# Looping a re.search fails to detect February month number and return proper month

Tags: python, regex, loops

I'm trying to evaluate a regex to determine the month in a file name and return just the month name. My code looks like this:

def month(name):

```
if re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)1', name) or re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)+monthName[i]', name):
    return('January')
elif re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)2', name) or re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)+mon[i]', name):
    return("February")
    etc...
```

The file names are read in from a folder.
File name examples:

MLV A 1.4.16.pdf

MLV A 2.7.16.pdf

MLV N Jan 2016

My code is successfully able to determine the month name from all file examples shown, but what I'd like to eliminate all the 'elif's and put the first 'if' through a loop and have the proper month name returned.
When I put the 'if' through a loop I cannot seem to get the 2.7.16 (meaning February file name) to be returned as February.

Here is attempt at a loop solution:

def month(name):

```
    if re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)[1-12]', name) or re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)+monthName[i]', name):
        return('January')     # or February etc...
```

I've also tried:

def month(name):

```
monthName = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']
monthNumber = ['1','2','3','4']
for i in range(len(monthName)):
    for j in monthNumber:
    if re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)+monthNumber[j]', name) or re.search('(?<=MLV\s.\s)+monthName[i]', name):
            return('January')     # or February etc...
```

Of course I'll also need to figure out how to return 'February' when '2' is found in the re.search for the monthNumber.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try to get the part of the filename that correspond to the month name, then match it:

```
months = {'1': 'January', 'Jan': 'January', '2': 'February', 'Feb': 'February', ...}

matcher = re.search('MLV\s.\s(\w+)', name)
try:
    return months[matcher.group(1)]
except:
    return None
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked perfectly and I applied this same method to Day and Year formats in the program. This compressed a lot of repetitious code. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a hybrid approach- Here `calendar.month_name` is a regular dictionary you can get month name by giving integer corresponds to that month e.g. `1` for `January`. If you want short form of months then use `calendar.month_abbr` instead of `calendar.month_name` e.g.`calendar.month_abbr[1]` will give `'Jan'`

```
from dateutil import parser
import calendar,re

txt = """MLV A 1.4.16.pdf

MLV A 2.7.16.pdf

MLV N Jan 2016"""

for x,date,y in re.findall(r'(MLV\s*\w\s*)(.*?)($|.pdf)',txt):
    d=parser.parse(date)
    print "'{0}' has month {1}".format(date,calendar.month_name[d.month])
```

Output-

```
'1.4.16' has month January
'2.7.16' has month February
'Jan 2016' has month January
```

`re.findall(r'(MLV\s*\w\s*)(.*?)($|.pdf)',txt)` will return `[('MLV A ', '1.4.16', '.pdf'), ('MLV A ', '2.7.16', '.pdf'), ('MLV N ', 'Jan 2016', '')]`

For details of regular expression used here, see <kbd>[LIVEDEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hG1sI9/1)</kbd>

**Even more details (with year)- you can add day too, here, i omitted since your data does not have day for all**-

```
from dateutil import parser
import re

txt = """MLV A 1.4.16.pdf

MLV A 2.7.16.pdf

MLV N Jan 2016"""

for x,date,y in re.findall(r'(MLV\s*\w\s*)(.*?)($|.pdf)',txt):
    d=parser.parse(date)
    print "'{0}' == {1} {2}".format(date,d.strftime("%B"),d.strftime("%Y"))
```

Output-

```
'1.4.16' == January 2016
'2.7.16' == February 2016
'Jan 2016' == January 2016
```

For details of `strftime` formatting see [here](http://strftime.org/).